# Neo4j : How to remove or filter node from set of all nodes with conditions on relations

Tags: neo4j

Suppose I have an image node, I have different relations on that image node.say RATES VIEWS etc
I want to remove images based on a particular relationship with the condition on that relationship.
e.g

```
match(i:Image)
where NOT (i)<-[r:RATES]-(u:User{userId:"123"})
and r.rate>5
return i
```

Here I want to find all images which are not rated by user and which are having rating greater than 5.

I am unable to find the solutions for it

Comment: I think you're going to have to clarify this a bit. It's easy enough to find images that haven't been rated by a user, but it sounds like you're looking for an image that hasn't been rated by a particular user, and the nonexistent rating (since it hasn't been rated by that particular user) should be greater than 5, which is of course impossible. Is this meant to be an OR instead of an AND? Or are you trying to figure out images that have been rated on average as a 5 or greater by all who have rated it? Or something else?

Comment: Let me clarify the scenario, 
I have all images say 100 and out of those, user has rated say 10 .

Comment: Continue.......Let me clarify the scenario, 
I have all images say 100 and out of those, User has rated say 10 .
Now out of those 10 , User have given 4 images rating grated than 5.
So our condition satisfies the 4 images So I should be able to get 94 images ignoring the 6 images which user has given less than 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification, it is a slightly tricky query. Since it seems like we'll be returning most of the images anyway, it should be okay to start the match with the user and all :Images. We can then use an OPTIONAL MATCH on the :RATES relationship between the user and the image, and r will be null if no such relationship exists. That will let us use WITH with one more predicate where we'll keep only rows where the relationship doesn't exist to the given :Image, or where the user has rated that :Image greater than 5.

```
MATCH (u:User{userId:"123"}), (i:Image)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r:RATES]->(i)
WITH i
WHERE r IS NULL OR r.rate > 5
RETURN i
```

Note the usage of the WHERE clause on the WITH instead of on the OPTIONAL MATCH. If we had placed the WHERE on the OPTIONAL MATCH instead, it would not have filtered out the rows where the user has rated the image less than or equal to 5, it would have returned null for r in those cases, which would have made the query incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

To find "all images which are not rated by user and which are having rating greater than 5":

```
MATCH (i:Image)<-[r:RATES]-(u:User)
WITH i, COLLECT(r.rating) AS ratings, COLLECT(u.userId) AS ids
WHERE ANY(r IN ratings WHERE r > 5) AND (NOT '123' IN ids)
RETURN i;
```